# Is there a good way to check when a variable stop changing its value after continuously changing for a while?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, time, nstimer

I'm trying to check a variable declared as
    `@property (assign, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval rate;` which is changing constantly as a time counter. In other words, the variable's value is changing continuously when the time has passed, I know that I can use KVO with
`- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:...}` function to observe when the variable changed its value, but I also need to know when the variable stop changing and become constant. I tried one way which is just checking the variable's value after very small amount of time (ex, 0.00001 second) using `NSTimer` here

```
    - (void) checkPlaying:(NSTimer*)t {

        NSLog(@"%f %f", self.keepRate, (double)self.rate);
        return self.keepRate != (double)self.rate;
    }


    - (void) isPlaying{

    self.keepRate = (double)self.rate;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.00001
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkPlaying:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
   }
```

and compared it to the previous stored value, but this also does not work; the value of `self.keepRate` and `(double)self.rate;` are still the same in that NSLog. I thought it will call `checkPlaying` after 0.00001 second, but I might misunderstand something. Could anyone help? Or it might also be good if anyone just come up with an idea to check when the variable stop changing. Thanks

Edit: Actually, the variable started changing its value when a user pushed a button, and it would stop changing value after the user pushed the same button. That's why I guess maybe I might need 0.0001 something seconds to check if the variable's value has changed or not. I knew that I could just use the button to check whether the value is changing or not, but there are A LOT more issues and things to handle if I do that, and that's why I asked this questions instead.

Comment: How about remembering last 5,100..x values (observeValue, remember with sum/avg etc) and if they don't change declare it stabilised? Also 0.00001 interval is brutal. 0.05 is sufficient

Comment: In KVO notification you can check that is it a new value or not a new value KVO already provide this mechanism. Just keep one bool variable to set and reset. If new value set bool isChanging = true else false.

Comment: @vivekDas Thanks a lot for your reply, the issue is that when it stops changing, the key is not assigned by any new value isn't it? In other words, it might not call `observeValueForKeyPath`. Or could you explain more about that mechanism if I misunderstood something?

Comment: @MarekH Yes, that's what I was trying to do, but I have a problem with remembering process, since the value I tried to store are all the same even though it should change after some time passed as you could see that `self.keepRate` and `(double)self.rate` are the same. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion about 0.05 thing.

Comment: How long does it take for you to consider the value "no longer changing"? A second? Half of a second? 1/10th of a second? Is it that critical that you'd really want to say *"it hasn't changed for `0.00001` seconds, so now I know it's constant"* (that's ***1/100,000th*** of a second, if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: @DonMag It's actually depends on the user. Actually, the variable started to change when user pushed a button, and it will stop changing after user pushed the same button, so I am not sure, if a user push it as fast as he can, it might take maybe 1/100 something seconds haha, that's just my guess, but Thanks for pointing this out, I will edit my question.

Comment: Think about your question... On first button tap, *your code* will start a variable changing -- on second tap, *your code* will stop the variable changing. It seems to make perfect sense that on the second tap you ***also*** call your function that is supposed to "do something" when the var stops changing. If that's not correct, you'll either need to explain in much more detail what is actually going on, and why you cannot simply act on the button tap.

Comment: @DonMag Yes, the purpose of checking variable's change is actually for checking whether the video is playing or not. I think the better way to check it is to check the rate of the video instead of checking merely when the button is pushed. And it's actually GVRVideoView which there's still no support for rate yet. That's why I stuck at checking the rate of time of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Here is class declaration

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int keepRate;

@end
```

Below is implementation

```
@implementation MyClass
- (void)setKeepRate:(int)aKeepRate {
    int oldValue = _keepRate;
    if (oldValue == aKeepRate) {
        // The value is same as before, that means the value is constant now
        // Do whatever you want to do now
    }
    // Update underlaying variable with new value, regardless if it is same or not
    _keepRate = aKeepRate;
}
@end
```

You can do same for rate as well